# Prisma @updatedAt doesn't change on update

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

So I've been working on a NestJS backend using postgresql and prisma, what I've noticed during testing, is that when I update one of the records using the `.update()` function from prisma, it doesn't actually update the `updatedAt` field; this is the example of one of my prisma models:

```
model Channel {
    id           String    @id @default(uuid())
    name         String?
    description  String?
    type         String    @default("DIRECT")
    password     String?
    firstOwnerId String?
    ownerId      String?
    adminIds     String[]  @default([])
    mutes        Mute[]
    kicks        Kick[]
    users        User[]
    messages     Message[]

    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

    @@map("channels")
}
```

this is how I can the updating function:

```js
    await this.prismaService.channel.update({
        where: {
          id: channelId,
        },
        data: {
          users: {
            connect: {
              id: userId,
            },
          },
        },
        include: channelIncludes,
      });
```

I am using the latest version of Prisma and NestJS `"@prisma/client": "^5.1.1"` and `"@nestjs/common": "^10.2.2"`

I gave the SQL migration generated by Prisma a look, and I noticed that the `updatedAt` doesn't really have something that will get it updated on change;

```sql
CREATE TABLE "channels" (
    "id" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT,
    "description" TEXT,
    "type" TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DIRECT',
    "password" TEXT,
    "firstOwnerId" TEXT,
    "ownerId" TEXT,
    "adminIds" TEXT[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::TEXT[],
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "channels_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I believe it should have something like; `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm seeing it too. Prisma doesn't update the field.

Comment: I got the same problem, this is really annoying bug.

Comment: I am getting the same problem, does anyone found a fix yet?

Answer (score 0):

Prisma updates the @updatedAt field in the underlying [engine](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-engines/blob/dbb3fbf70767fdfaf10393b40e7f215119925d3f/query-engine/connectors/query-connector/src/write_args.rs#L393). The `Channel` model has either a One-to-Many relationship with the foreign key on the `Users` table (where I assume you have a `channelId` field) or an implicit Many-to-Many relation where prisma manages the relation table itself.

In both cases, prisma is not writing to the `channels` table and therefore doesn't touch update the 'updatedAt' field on `channels`. It's either updating the `channelId` foreign key on the `users` table or the internal `_ChannelsToUsers` table prisma creates.

A proposed workaround would be to tell prisma to update `updatedAt` during the query. (Note that if you have a Many-to-Many relationship this won't update the `users` table.)

```
    await this.prismaService.channel.update({
        where: {
          id: channelId,
        },
        data: {
>>>       updatedAt: new Date(),
          users: {
            connect: {
              id: userId,
            },
          },
        },
        include: channelIncludes,
      });
```

If you have a Many-to-Many you will need to either update the user in the query by adding `update: { where: { id: userId }, data: { updatedAt: new Date() }}`  to the `user` part of the query args if prisma handles it properly or a second write, potentially as part of a transaction.